# $G$ has exactly three subgroups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

> [image]

**My attempt for the first:** (*I would like to get it verified because I didn't use property of a cyclic group*) $|G|<\infty$ (since for otherwise $(a^2),(a^3)$ are distinct improper nontrivial subgroups) can't have more than one prime divisor since for otherwise $G$ would contain more than one element of those order (and hence subgroups which must be nontrivial proper).

Since $|G|\ne 1,~|G|=p^k$  for some prime $p$ and for some $k\ge1.$

The existence of $H$ ensures $k>1.$

However if $k>2$ by Sylow theorem $G$ would contain at least two proper subgroups of orders $p,p^2.$

So $k=2.~\Box$

**My attempt for the second:** Since the argument for the *first* didn't use the property of a cyclic group, $|G|=p^2$ for some prime $p.$ Consequently $G$ is abelian and hence the isomorphic classed are $$\mathbb Z_{p^2}\\\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$$Since $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_p$ has at least two proper subgroup viz. $\langle(1,0)\rangle,\langle(0,1)\rangle$ we have $G\simeq\mathbb Z_{p^2},$ cyclic $\Box.$

> *Please tell me if I'm correct!!*

Comment: When you say that $|G|<\infty$, are you assuming that in an infinite group, there must exist an element of infinite order?

Comment: There are proofs that use much less machinery, **and** are simpler.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Yes, for cyclic case. $G$ being abelian the generator I think is of infinite order.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Is by any mean I'm wrong?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, Sriti Mallick: In the first case you must take $a$ to be a generator of the group, since the group is cyclic. Then $a^2$ and $a^3$ will generate two distinct proper subgroup.

Comment: @Sriti Mallick: For the second case, if $G$ is not cyclic, there exist $a\in G$ and $b \in G \setminus \langle a \rangle$ and it is easy to see that $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$ form two proper subgroup of $G$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Sriti Mallick: The first one is correct, if you take $a$ to be a generator. The second case is incorrect. You should not use the first case. You can use the above hint that i have given.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54902/how-to-find-all-groups-that-have-exactly-3-subgroups/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first one you might use the fact that the number of subgroups of a cyclic group of order $n$ equals the number of divisors $d(n)$ of $n$. For a prime $p$, $d(p^k)=k+1$, and hence $k=2$.

For the second statement: pick any $g \in G$, with $g \neq 1$. Then $<g>$ is non-trivial, hence equal to $G$ or a proper subgroup. In the latter case pick $h \in G\backslash<g>$. Then we must have $<h>=G$. So $G$ is cyclic either way.

Answer (score 0):

Let if possible $G$ is infinite. There can't exist any element of infinite order. Otherwise we will get infinite number of subgroups of $G$. Again, if each of the element has finite order we will get infinite number of subgroups since $G$ is infinite.

This left us with only the finite case. $|G|$ will not have more then one distinct prime divisors. Otherwise we will get more than three subgroups. Hence, $|G|=p^{\alpha}$ for some prime $p,\alpha \geq 0$. Clearly, $\alpha\geq 2$. Now by the property of $p$-groups, $\alpha=2$. Because, if $|G|=p^{\alpha}$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$ for each $\alpha \geq k\geq 0$. Hence, $G$ is abelian and $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. The later has $p+1=\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}$ subgroups. Therefore, $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: The latter has $p+1$ subgroups, not four.

Comment: @orione Exactly. Thank you.