# Condition for which $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ has exactly $\displaystyle k$ subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is a condition for which  $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ has exaclty $k$ subgroups?

For example, if $k = 2$ then I belive the condition is that $n$ is a prime number.

Generally, I think the number of subgroups of  $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ are the number of dividers of $n$. Meaning there are going to be $k$ subgroups when $n$ has $k$ dividers such that all of them do $ k | n$

I already know the proof has to do with the fact that the only subgroups of  $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ are going to be $k \displaystyle \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ such that $k|n$.

But how could I prove it?

Comment: A cyclic group of order $n$ has a subgroup of order $d$ if and only if $d|n$, and in that case, the subgroup is unique.

Comment: Try to show that subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic and then proceed from there. As a hint, consider using the division algorithm.

Comment: I've been thinking of a proof for hours but nothing. Could you help me further?

Comment: ...but nothing. OK, it doesn't hurt to search this site a bit then. For $k=3$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496000/g-has-exactly-three-subgroups). Then $n=p^2$. Can you find more? And did you try to follow the hint by Arturo?