# Finite group with three proper subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The Klein-$4$ group is ***a finite group with exactly three subgroups*** $H$ such that $1<H<G$.

Conversely, if $G$ is a finite group with exactly three subgroups $H$ such that $1<H<G$, then what can be said about $G$?

Comment: The number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is precisely the number of divisors of $n$. So take $n$ with $5$ divisors and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has precisely three non-trivial proper subgroups.

Comment: A cyclic group of order $p^4$, $p$ a prime, will also work. Wonder if there are any others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that $G$ must be either the Klein four, or a cyclic group of order $p^4$ for some prime $p$.

- A cyclic group of order $\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{a_i}$ has $\prod_i(a_i+1)$
  subgroups (including the trivial ones), so $k=1, a_1=4$ is the only
  possibility.
- A non-cyclic abelian group $G$ has a subgroup $H$ isomorphic to $C_p\times
     C_p$. That group has $p+1$ proper subgroups, so we must have $p=2$ and $H=G$. This leaves the Klein four as the only alternative.
- A non-abelian $p$-group $G$ has $G/[G,G]$ as a non-cyclic abelian head, so the argument of the previous bullet works.
- A finite non-$p$-group with a non-normal Sylow subsgroup has at least three Sylow subgroups of that order, so that is ruled out, because it has at least one more Sylow subgroup.
- That leaves the case of a non-abelian group $G$ such that all its Sylow subgroups are normal. Then $G$ thus a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, and one of those has order $p^3$ at least, because otherwise $G$ is abelian. We are done.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the last three bullets can be compressed...

Comment: I am almost certain I have answered this question previously (as well as variations with other small numbers of subgroups), but I am on my phone right now, which is terrible for looking up duplicates.

Comment: Can't say I am surprised, @Tobias. With that hint looking for a dup should become easier.

Comment: Hmm. [This is related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54905/11619) but different. Not the same though because there the trivial subgroups were included.

Comment: Ahh, I might have remembered that part wrong then. I think I have also answered one more like it, but that was probably the case between these two, with 4 total.